# err_too_many_redirects when trying to redirect non www to www

Tags: linux, apache, redirect, apache2, apache2.4

Inside virtuahost apache conf file

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

I tried to put these code inside apache conf file

```
ServerName example.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

also I tried,

```
< If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'YOUR-DOMAIN.com'">
Redirect "/" "http://www.YOUR-DOMAIN.com/"
</If>
```

also did this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    # real server configuration
</VirtualHost>
```

I checked also official apache https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html#canonicalhost

Comment: I don't see what 's wrong with your configuration.  Could it be that the redirect is cached in your browser?

Comment: The error says too many redirects, do you have all of these in place at once? Perhaps it's performing more than one of your solutions.

Comment: @ Joey Harwood I did not understand the question I am a newbie | @ Gerard H. Pille I cleared the cache also tried on different device.

Comment: @JoeyHarwood the error may not be in the lines you show us.  It's hard to debug when you don't show the complete Apache config.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille This isn't my question. You should use `@Mark178` to respond to the OP.

Comment: @Mark178 Server configs are not my specialty so take what I say with a grain of salt. What I'm saying is if you write code to redirect in three separate places in your config, it seems likely to me that you are getting the `err_too_many_redirects` because because more than one of those are executing. Gerard is right, that posting the whole config in your question makes it easier for others to help debug.

Comment: How can I copy all apache config file?

Comment: @Mark178 Looks like your using nano, google `nano copy all text` or something similar to find that answer.

Comment: @JoeyHarwood Sorry!

Comment: @Mark178  You could put all conf files on a file share, or else: `find /etc/apache2 -name '*.conf' -exec echo "## {}" \; -exec cat {} \;` (which is all on one line).

Comment: I am not able to copy